# Highchart tick interval for 5 days

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I cannot seem to figure out how to set my tick interval correctly.
Need to have tick with 5 day difference on the X axis. I want to display x-axis like '1 march , 5 march , 10 march , 15 march ' etc

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/96x5dz5c/1/)

Java script given below

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    zoomType: 'x'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate from 2006 through 2008'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                            'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' :
                            'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    tickInterval:24 * 3600 * 1000,
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Exchange rate'
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    area: {
                        fillColor: {
                            linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1},
                            stops: [
                                [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                                [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                            ]
                        },
                        marker: {
                            radius: 2
                        },
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                lineWidth: 1
                            }
                        },
                        threshold: null
                    }
                },

                series: [{
                    type: 'area',
                    name: 'USD to EUR',
                    pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                    pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 2, 1),
                    data: [[140],[127],[35],[132],[192],[179],[131],[206],[92],[57],[352],[370],[281],[282],[128],[100],[33],[215],[154],[226],[225],[334],[105],[60],[264],[227],[151],[115],[184],[74]]        
                }]
            });
            });
            </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong here? It shows number after April because you didn't say what it should show after April.

Comment: I want show full data between Jan and April

Comment: It is showing the data that you indicated in your series.data array. What do you mean the full data?

Comment: If the data is "between Jan and April" then you have to give them specific dates. It can't just guess where the points are. You could insert empty labels between each month if you insist on `category`, but sounds like a `datetime` kind of thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always use `tickPositioner`, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/96x5dz5c/2/

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickInterval:24 * 3600 * 1000 * 5,
    tickPositioner: function(min, max){
         var interval = this.options.tickInterval,
             ticks = [],
             count = 0;

        while(min < max) {
            ticks.push(min);
            min += interval;
            count ++;
        }

        ticks.info = {
            unitName: 'day',
            count: 5,
            higherRanks: {},
            totalRange: interval * count
        }


        return ticks;
    }
},
```

Comment: Your answer is correct this is what i want exactly.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The tick problem is a feature of Highcharts. It doesn't support all numbers as intervals, what I mean is reported here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1104

Which means you can't do what you want with Highcharts. 
I recommend you to take a look at jquery flot. It supports what you want. https://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt